# There is no selection to install Android Studio

Tags: android

Tried to install Android Studio, I run android-studio-bundle-143.2739321-windows.exe. The "Android Studio Setup" window appeared with 3 selections:
Android Studio(without tick), Android SDK(with tick) and Android Virtual Device(with tick).
That means I cannot install Android Studio?!
Do you know what is wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Install intelliJ instead of android studio cause its faster and if you ever want to do html,css,java etc, you can do that.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion!
What I need is to develop some apps for mobile. Can  intelliJ develop such apps, perhaps in an emulator or in a connected mobile?